# VBA validating if column contains email

Tags: regex, vba, excel, email

I'm not very used to programming in VBA. My goal is to make a script that I can pass to my collueges since they have long Excel files with a column containing multiple words including one email address. Ex: company user user@company.com

I'm stuck with my regex passing through all data and can't seem to make it filter out anything.

```
Function isEmail(ByVal data As String)

Dim mailReg As Object
Set mailReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

Dim regpattern As String
regpattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$" 'Expression ok

Dim arr1() As String
Dim element As Variant
Dim strInput As String

arr1() = Split(data, " ")

For Each element In arr1

    If regpattern <> "" Then
    strInput = element

    With mailReg
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = regpattern
    End With

MsgBox (strInput)

End If
Next element 
End Function
```

I have also tried to use

```
For Each element In arr1

If element Like regpattern Then
MsgBox (element)

End If
Next element 
End Function
```

But then nothing appears in the MsgBox..

Comment: Why `If regpattern <> "" Then` - isn't it supposed to be `If element<> ""` Then`

Comment: This code is a mess. The regex is not correct. What are you trying to do? Show a message with each email found in a string? Then use a `Sub`, not a `Function`.

Comment: Email addresses can include non-aphanumeric characters, like ", !, # and $.  Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address).

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Const MODULE_NAME As String = "modMail"

    '' Validate email address
    Public Function ValidateEmailAddress(ByVal strEmailAddress As String) As Boolean
        On Error GoTo Catch

        Dim objRegExp As New RegExp
        Dim blnIsValidEmail As Boolean

        objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
        objRegExp.Global = True
        objRegExp.Pattern = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$"

        blnIsValidEmail = objRegExp.Test(strEmailAddress)
        ValidateEmailAddress = blnIsValidEmail

        Exit Function

    Catch:
        ValidateEmailAddress = False
        MsgBox "Module: " & MODULE_NAME & " - ValidateEmailAddress function" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "Error#:  " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    End Function
```

Comment: Why do you think OP needs a boolean result?

Comment: Thanks! I added boolean to check which element in the array contained the mail address and then copy it.
It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Got it to print out the mailaddress with this code:
Thanks to braX!

```
Function isEmail(ByVal data As String)

Dim mailReg As Object
Set mailReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

Dim regpattern As String
regpattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$" 'Expression ok

Dim arr1() As String
Dim element As Variant
Dim strInput As String

arr1() = Split(data, " ")

For Each element In arr1

    strInput = element
    mailReg.IgnoreCase = True
    mailReg.Global = True
    mailReg.Pattern = regpattern

    If mailReg.Test(strInput) = True Then

    MsgBox (strInput)
    End If
Next element
End Function
```